# How do I create a variable with a formula in a cell but when i call it everything that isnt absolute changes its row number to the current row?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This is the formula I wish to call as a variable.

I wish to call this variable within a formula because its used 4 times in a single larger formula. The problem is when I call it, despite it being the same text it doesn't work I suspect because the cell coordinates don't change to the row its being called to, is there anything that can be done?

Comment: Post some sample data and expected output. Also put your current formula.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.